# Unable to install super-gradients (treelib version not found)

Tags: yolo, treelib

I am trying to "pip install super-gradients" and I get an error that "ImportError: cannot import name '**version**' from 'treelib'". See below for full traceback.

Is there a reason why **version** is not accessible? I am on Windows, Spyder 5.4.3, Python 3.8.10.

And could someone please tag this with "super-gradients"? Thank you.

Full traceback:

```
pip install super-gradients
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting super-gradients
  Using cached super_gradients-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.9.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.57.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (4.65.0)
Collecting boto3>=1.17.15 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached boto3-1.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.2.0 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from super-gradients) (4.17.3)
Collecting Deprecated>=1.2.11 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached Deprecated-1.2.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python>=4.5.1 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (4.5.5.64)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.6.1 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from super-gradients) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.3.4 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from super-gradients) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.8.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (5.9.5)
Collecting tensorboard>=2.4.1 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=21.0.0 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from super-gradients) (66.0.0)
Collecting coverage~=5.3.1 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached coverage-5.3.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (212 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.10.0 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (0.14.1)
Collecting sphinx~=4.0.2 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached Sphinx-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Collecting sphinx-rtd-theme (from super-gradients)
  Using cached sphinx_rtd_theme-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.8 MB)
Collecting torchmetrics==0.8 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached torchmetrics-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (408 kB)
Collecting hydra-core>=1.2.0 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached hydra_core-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (154 kB)
Collecting omegaconf (from super-gradients)
  Using cached omegaconf-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting onnxruntime==1.13.1 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached onnxruntime-1.13.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (5.9 MB)
Collecting onnx==1.13.0 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached onnx-1.13.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (12.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3,>=5.3.0 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from super-gradients) (9.4.0)
Collecting pip-tools>=6.12.1 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached pip_tools-6.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.5 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting einops==0.3.2 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached einops-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting pycocotools==2.0.6 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached pycocotools-2.0.6.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf==3.20.3 in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from super-gradients) (3.20.3)
Collecting treelib==1.6.1 (from super-gradients)
  Using cached treelib-1.6.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_eldz5ej\treelib_f0d5ee2532f0448da840362e00ef7cc2\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      from treelib import __version__
  ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'treelib' (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\treelib\__init__.py)
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have treelib 1.6.4, as shown via "pip show..."

```
pip show treelib
Version: 1.6.4
```

However, I can't seem to access the **version**.

```
import treelib
print(treelib.__version__)


  File c:\data\objectrecognition\test2.py:11
    print(treelib.__version__)

AttributeError: module 'treelib' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I am trying to install super-gradients so that I can try YOLO-NAS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that will be helpful,
but I had some problems when running:

```
pip install super-gradients
```

so i tried:

```
pip install super-gradients==3.1.0
```

and it worked fine for me

Comment: thanks, it still does not work, i suspect it is something specific to my system, as I could install it on my other machine.